# Select all the keys inside arrays (inside another array) that contain the same value

Tags: php, arrays

My point here is, some keys with the value "nit" are have the same value in many arrays (such as arrays 21, 23 and 24). I want to select all the arrays that have the same "nit" and create a new array with all of those. I need one array (from all the ones with same "nit") to remain in the main array(randomly pick one).

```
[20] => Array
            (
                [fecha] => 2018-08-27 18:38:49
                [id_cliente] => 
                [nit] => 50255872726
                [destino] => Copartes.Gt
                [nombre] => Registrar Cliente
                [telefono] => 55872726
                [type] => IN
                [mensaje] => Mandame el número de cuenta y te voy a depositar
            )

        [21] => Array
            (
                [fecha] => 2018-08-27 18:36:20
                [id_cliente] => 110099
                [nit] => 3108449-4
                [destino] => Copartes.Gt
                [nombre] => Guillermo Suhr
                [telefono] => 42150465
                [type] => IN
                [mensaje] => Muchas gracias
            )

        [22] => Array
            (
                [fecha] => 2018-08-27 18:30:05
                [id_cliente] => 27523
                [nit] => 1241764-5
                [destino] => Copartes.Gt
                [nombre] => Manuel Garcia
                [telefono] => 53186931
                [type] => IN
                [mensaje] => Gracias
            )

        [23] => Array
            (
                [fecha] => 2018-08-27 18:30:00
                [id_cliente] => 110099
                [nit] => 3108449-4
                [destino] => Copartes.Gt
                [nombre] => Guillermo Suhr
                [telefono] => 42150465
                [type] => IN
                [mensaje] => Gracias
            )

        [24] => Array
            (
                [fecha] => 2018-08-27 18:30:00
                [id_cliente] => 110099
                [nit] => 3108449-4
                [destino] => Copartes.Gt
                [nombre] => Guillermo Suhr
                [telefono] => 42150465
                [type] => IN
                [mensaje] => Buena tarde
```

Comment: See [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to the job of a database inside your PHP code. Since the data probably came *out* of a data base, then thats where you should be getting your results from.

Comment: They don't have the same value. (See `mensaje`).

Comment: I know they dont have the same message, but their "nit" is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just [filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) the array:

```
$a = array_filter($a, function($val) {
    static $set = []; // collect nits
    $nit = $val['nit'];
    if (!isset($set[$nit])) { // new nit
        return $set[$nit] = true; // true
    }
    return false;
});
```

Explanation:
The filter callback is a function that is called for each array element. (Since there are no flags passed to `array_filter()`, the callback receives the array value only.) This function has a [static variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) which exists only local in the function scope and doesn't lose it's value when the function call has completed. It collects all nit values so far and returns `true` if seen for the first time and `false` else.

Comment: Honestly, I am surprised with the code, since it worked perfectly! However, I don't fully understand it. Could you explain it to me please?

Comment: @OscarParedez Hope it got clearer with this explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I always find the easiest thing to do here is a simple foreach loop to sort your items into another array grouped by the key you wish, in my reduced example, I've used `category`...

```
// Source Data
$array = array(
  array( 'category' => 10, 'name' => 'aaa' ),
  array( 'category' => 11, 'name' => 'bbb' ),
  array( 'category' => 12, 'name' => 'ccc' ),
  array( 'category' => 10, 'name' => 'ddd' ),
  array( 'category' => 11, 'name' => 'eee' ),
  array( 'category' => 11, 'name' => 'fff' ),
  array( 'category' => 13, 'name' => 'ggg' ),
);

// Create a container using "category"
$groups = array_fill_keys( array_unique( array_column( $array, 'category') ), array() );

// Loop and Sort
foreach( $array as $index => $item )
{
  $groups[ $item['category'] ][ $index ] = $item;
}

// Done
print_r( $groups );
```

Once you've got this, list you're now able to figure out which have multiple records or not by the count within each sub array.